# How to get two scripts src from iframe using jquery or vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get two scripts src from iframe using jquery or javascript

```
<div id="mytesting">
    <iframe src="index.html" id="testing" >
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://google.com/javascript.js"></script>
 <!-- i want to get below src the src will change every time  -->
    <script src="http://testing.com"></script>
<!--   i want to get above src the src will change every time -->
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>


    </iframe>
</div>
```

In this I want to get second src using jquery or javascript.

Comment: Where are you stuck? jQuery lets you find elements by their tag name, choose the second of the ones you find, and get attributes from elements. The [API is well-documented](http://api.jquery.com). What part has you stumped?

Comment: i don't know jquery can you give the code

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the code" site. It's a site for helping people with problems with the code they've written. If you read the API documentation and look at the examples, you'll have what you need to do this within an hour, two at most. If you run into trouble at that point, show what you've tried, say why you thought it would work, and what you're seeing instead of the desired result.

Comment: I tried one code but i am not getting i am asking how to get

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways you can select the `src` attribute in your code, I'd recommend you first give it an id like this:

```
<script id="myscript" src="http://testing.com/javascript.js"></script>
```

You can then select that element by its id using `$("#myscript")`. The code for getting the `src` attribute is

```
var source = $("#myscript").attr('src');
```

If you don't want to add an `id` attribute, you can use a different selector, for example, you can select the second script tag in the head like this: `$("head script:nth-child(2)")`. Be careful though, because if someone adds another `script` element in the `head` above this element, this will no longer work.

Comment: sorry anthony  the script  tag we are getting dynamically so how i kept for dynamic script

Comment: i am not getting src from your code can you update the script

Comment: $("head script:nth-child(2)").attr('src');

Comment: not getting it saying undefined can you kept  a alert and see what your getting.